# PhantomJS path on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, selenium, heroku, phantomjs

I have a node app running on Heroku. I am scraping a website using selenium in python and calling the python script from my node app whenever I need to. I installed PhantomJS on my mac and when I run the app locally (node index.js), everything works just fine.

```
path_to_phantom = '/Users/govind/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-
macosx/bin/phantomjs'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path_to_phantom)
```

However, nothing seems to work on Heroku. I also added the [PhantomJS buildpack](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) to my node app but it just doesn't call the python script. The problem I think is the path to PhantomJS buildpack. What path should I add? Or is there any other aspect I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I managed to solve this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to use Selenium with PhantomJS in my Python application deployed to Heroku following these steps:

1) Switch to using the Cedar-14 stack on my Heroku application

```
$ heroku stack:set cedar-14
```

2) Install a PhantomJS buildpack

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs
```

With these changes I could then use Selenium to fetch websites

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("http://www.google.com")  # This does not throw an exception if it got a 404

html = browser.page_source
print html  # If this outputs more than just '<html><head></head><body></body></html>' you know that it worked
```